# Use Correct Version Of Vendor DLL Depending On User-Installed Software

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Trying to use the right version of a vendor assembly, depending on which version of the vendor software is installed on the user's machine.  This question is very similar, but the suggestions given don't seem to work:

[How to use two different Microsoft Interop assemblies in one project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372068/how-to-use-two-different-microsoft-interop-assemblies-in-one-project?rq=1)

The crux of the matter is that I need to instantiate a particular version of the namespace and class, depending on the user machine situation.  I don't want to use both assemblies for various purposes; just the right one.  Some actual code, using WordPerfect and its API, PerfectScript:

This is the simple set-up, using only the WPx4 dll

```
using WordPerfect;

namespace WP_PS_Tools {

public class WP_PerfectScript {
    public PerfectScript perfectScript { get; set; }
    public IntPtr _wpHandle { get; set; }

    /**
     * Initialize perfect script object
     */
    public WP_PerfectScript()
    {
        perfectScript = new PerfectScript();
    }
...
```

No problems here. The "WordPerfect" reference is to a Primary Interop Assembly that I created from the vendor's "wpwin14.tlb".

However, some of my users have WPx6 installed, so they need to use the newer WPx6 dll.  These dlls are very similar, with nearly identical methods, and share the same class name and can share the same namespace (depending on how I create the Primary Interop Assembly).

I first tried using the route attempted by this question: [Allowing multiple versions of the same COM library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460689/allowing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-com-library), for which there is a very cryptic and unfinished description by Microsoft on how to modify an assembly to include 2 versions: [How to: Wrap Multiple Versions of Type Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1565h6hc.aspx).  I also could not figure out how to add another assembly to an existing one, plus I was not convinced that would actually help.

The next futile attempt was to try to somehow abstract the class so that one or the other could be called, depending on the particular installation:

```
using Corel.WordPerfect14;

namespace WP_PS_Tools {

public class WP14_PerfectScript {
    public virtual PerfectScript perfectScript { get; set; }
    public IntPtr _wpHandle { get; set; }

    /**
     * Initialize perfect script object
     */
    public WP14_PerfectScript()
    {
        perfectScript = new PerfectScript();
    } 
.
.
.

using Corel.WordPerfect16;

namespace WP_PS_Tools
{
public class WP16_PerfectScript: WP14_PerfectScript
{
    public PerfectScript perfectScript { get; set; }


    public WP16_PerfectScript()
    {
        perfectScript = new PerfectScript();
    }
}
}
```

This did not even compile, because of the main problem:  the property perfectScript has to be cast as one or the other versions of the PerfectScript types (in this example, the class Corel.WordPerfect14.PerfectScript or Corel.WordPerfect16.PerfectScript).  Inserting "new" did as expected:  I got a version of the WPx4 dll running perfectly (but unable to interact with the already running WPx6 program).  As far as I know, there is no other more abstract type than the PerfectScript class itself, so I can't use that class to inherit from.

I also tried naming the two assemblies exactly the same, but Visual Studio would not let me reference them with the same name.  Then I tried creating the assemblies with the same name and then renaming the file name.  I was allowed to add them as references, but ended up with the ambiguity of class names other questions have mentioned.

Next I tried using the extern alias keyword, but ended up with the same type casting problem.

There must be a simple answer to this problem!  It sure would be nice if "virtual" in a property meant you could override the type, but alas, that is not the case.

I guess I may just need to compile two versions of my application, with the different references, but that solution is less than desirable.

Comment: I guess my question is too convoluted to warrant a response. Maybe what I am trying to do is impossible in C#.  I have a code in my application that uses the external WP dll.  I don't want to create multiple parallel classes that do exactly the same thing, except that they call a different library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run PerfectScript commands through the version of WordPerfect that is installed on the computer, but you dont want to have to compile/install/maintain multiple versions of your software to do so.

My solution to this problem was to implement a plugin system for the software I maintain. There are multiple resources out on the 'net and what works for me is this implementation of the  [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

1. Define an abstract class interface you want to run your scripts through. This class exists in your application and is not concerned with the different versions of WordPerfect. This class needs to reside in a DLL of its own that your application links against because it is going to be shared amongst the plugins you are going to create.
2. Implement the abstract class for each version of WordPerfect you support. Put each implementation into its own DLL. Thus, each DLL is only concerned with a specific version of WordPerfect.
3. Load the dll for the matching WordPerfect installed on the client's machine at runtime with System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String)
4. Iterate through the types in the assembly, find one that implements the abstract class, get a ConstructorInfo to that type and invoke it.

The end goal here is to use .net's reflection abilities to construct a very specific class at runtime. You don't really care the specific details of the class, just that it implements your abstract class to give it a common interface that you can work with the versions of WordPerfect that you support.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have spent some hours trying to understand and implement this idea.  The factory method pattern is intriguing but difficult to grasp for my still newbie brain.  Couple of questions: Is it really necessary to put each assembly into its own DLL?  Seems like it could work by compiling each PS container with the correct PS version, each in its own project.  It also looks like the PS API calls will all be through late binding (without the VS intellisense helper notes).  And finally, I'm still not sure how to avoid the "using WordPerfect" reference ambiguity problem.  Thanks!

Comment: You could compile each PS version into its own project, sure, but I would say that you are punting on the problem (which you may need to do if you are time/budget limited). What is the plan for the next version of PS? You may need to have three different versions of your application to build/test/deploy.

Making DLL's is a lot like putting each PS container into its own project without all the extra code of your application in there, just the bits that make the PS stuff work. My (naive) assumption is that you have an application DLL for your plugins to link against.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the application DLL part in 1.

Comment: This is a good answer.  It may not help in your situation, but I found that the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) helped me to solve a similar issue.

Comment: Still having trouble making this work.  Forgetting about the DLLs for now, just trying to get the class structure correct.  The only way my main application can access any sort of PS command (without knowing the type) is to use the dynamic type.  But that causes all sorts of other problems because, although methods are ignored, enumerations are still unresolved.  Maybe I am doing this all wrong!

Comment: Finally got it to work, but not sure if I like it.  I built the application using one version of the PS DLL, from which Visual Studio extracted hundreds of enumerations.  I used those enumerations to select various options for the PS commands.  However, I now am forced to use the dynamic type and late binding, so all of those enumerations don't exist anymore. I need to convert all of those enumerations into integer values.  Not to mention Intellisense for PS does not work anymore, which puts a serious damper on the my coding speed.  Thanks! At least I understand the factory method better...